# How to toggle a HTML property without value dynamically in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I hope it render like this:

```
// normal
<div></div>
// when necessary, add a `data-locked` property without value to it
<div data-locked></div>
```

I tried `<div :data-locked='conditionBoolean'></div>`, but not works as I expected (`<div data-locked='true'></div>` I don't want the value true/false).

Why I need this? That's because a third party CSS dependency write so:

```css
[data-locked] { display: none }
```

Comment: If you realistically look at it, the value does not hurt. Doesn't it

Comment: Nope, actually there is a css dependency that  is using this attribute as toggler, it uses `[data-locked]` selector, the value makes no difference to the selector.

Comment: Ah, in such case yes. But no-one stops you from changing the CSS dep to `[data-locked="true"] { ...` right? It's more descriptive anyways ;)

Comment: Yes, if this question's answer is no way, I can only consider modifying the third party dependency...

Answer (score 1):

You could use `v-bind` here

```
<div v-bind="dataAttrs"></div>
```

and define a `computed` property

```
dataAttrs() {
  return this.conditionBoolean && { 'data-locked': '' }
}
```

Though you could achieve the similar behaviour using `v-show` without `data-locked`

```
<div v-show="!conditionBoolean"></div>
```